# How to get a list of manufacturers using SOAP in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, soap

I'm trying to list all the manufacturers names and ID in Magento through SOAP but I couldn't find a sample of code to do it. Can anyone help on how to achieve this using SOAP and PHP?

Comment: There's plenty of ways to do this, but it's hard to work out what you need in this case. Where is this data coming from? Do you wish to consume the SOAP feed or offer one? Is there a plugin in the Magento ecosystem that can help you?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using the Product Attributes API. Documentation link http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/product_attribute.info.html

The below code should get you an attribute and the values associated with it. You simply need to pass in the attribute code. Then pull out the `options` value from the response object which should contain an array of catalogAttributeOptionEntity which will be your options and values.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$result = $client->call($session, 'product_attribute.info', 'manufacturer');
var_dump ($result);

// If you don't need the session anymore
//$client->endSession($session);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to take a llok to this article that shows hos to easily consume the Magento SOAP Web service https://www.wsdltophp.com/Blog/Use-WsdlToPhp-to-manage-your-Magento-website-with-its-SOAP-API